# Convert List<char[]> into an Array char[] without using System.arraycopy()

Tags: java, arrays, char, java-stream

What's a simple way to convert/flatten a `List<char[]>` to `char[]` in Java?

I know I can do it by iterating the `List` and using `System.arraycopy`,  but I'm wondering is there a simpler way to do it using Java 8 streams?

Maybe something like this, but without having to box the primitive `char` to `Character`:

```
List<char[]> listOfCharArrays = ...

Character[] charArray =
    Stream.of(listOfCharArrays )
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .toArray(Character[]::new);
```

Comment: NO!! You can't! You are trying to convert a 2-Dimensional data structure to a 1-Dimensional.

Comment: @PapaifromBEKOAIL I mean, that's not an issue by itself. That's why `flatMap` exists in the first place: To flatten a "2-dimensional" source into a "1-dimenional" stream.

Comment: @PapaifromBEKOAIL There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Since there is no `char` primitive specialization of Stream (à la `IntStream`), I see no way to do this which is going to be more readable than the iterative solution. Even if there were, I strongly suspect that that the iterative solution would be much faster, since `arrayCopy` can copy blocks of memory, and the stream solution would have to process it one character at a time.

Comment: It could be done if you create a method `char[] concat(char[] array1, char[] array2)`. Then using `reduce` with identity element `new char[0]` you can simply concatenate all of these `char[]` elements into one `char[]`. This does have the drawback of creating a lot of intermediate `char[]`s. A simpler option requires two iterations - one to get the total length (can be done using a stream), and one to copy. I'd personally do the latter using a simple for loop because the start index for the `System.arraycopy` keeps changing, which needs some nasty tricks to get it working inside the stream.

Comment: @RobSpoor I've created a similar method using `CharBuffer`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72685373/589259).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes that's a nice combination of the concat (done by the `CharBuffer`) and the double looping to calculate the size.

Comment: Is your goal avoiding array copy because you'd like it to be cleaner and more maintainable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can think of only one thing, and that is to use [`CharBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html). For efficiency reasons I would always first calculate the right size, and then perform the copy. Any solution that performs multiple copies and/or performs string handling will be inefficient.

Here's the code. The first line calculates the total size of the array required, and then allocates just enough memory for it. The second line performs the copying using the aforementioned `put` method. The final line returns the `char[]` that is backing the `CharBuffer`.

```
CharBuffer fullBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(
        listOfCharArrays.stream().mapToInt(array -> array.length).sum());
listOfCharArrays.forEach(fullBuffer::put);
char[] asCharArray = fullBuffer.array();
```

Of course, I cannot guarantee that it won't use `System.arrayCopy` somewhere inside of the [`CharBuffer#put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#put-char:A-) method. I would strongly expect that it will use `System.arrayCopy` or similar code internally. That probably goes for most solutions provided here though.

It is possible to avoid the first size calculation by using a large enough buffer if you can estimate a maximum size, but it would require an additional copy of the data in the buffer; [`CharBuffer#array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#array--) *simply returns the correctly sized backing array*, which means that the data **is copied only once**.

---

You can also use `CharBuffer` directly if you want to use object oriented code. Beware that you need to make sure that you [`flip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--) it after writing to it though, and that `CharBuffer` is mutable (you can pass copies using the `duplicate` or `asReadOnly` methods - the returned instances reference the same buffer, but have independent, mutable "position" and "limit" fields).

The `Buffer` and Java NIO classes are slightly tricky to understand, but once you do you get great benefits from them, e.g. when using them for `CharEncoder` or memory mapped files.

Comment: If you do not want to predetermine the size, you can use `CharArrayWriter w = new CharArrayWriter(); listOfCharArrays.forEach(a -> w.write(a, 0, a.length)); char[] asCharArray = w.toCharArray();`

Answer (score 18):

This is the most readable version I can come up with. You can append all the char arrays to a String, via a StringBuilder, then convert that to a `char[]`.

```
char[] chars = listOfCharArrays.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::toString))
    .toCharArray();
```

Probably much slower than the iterative version, since `arrayCopy` can copy blocks of memory.

You could consider precomputing the total number of chars to avoid StringBuilder array reallocations, but this optimization and any others are going to eat into the readability gains you're getting from using streams.

```
int totalSize = listOfCharArrays.stream().mapToInt(arr -> arr.length).sum();
char[] chars = listOfCharArrays.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(() -> new StringBuilder(totalSize), //... the same
```

There are 2 unnecessary copies (`StringBuilder` -> `String`, `String` -> `char[]`) which are effectively a consequence of these classes not being perfectly suited to this task. `CharBuffer` is better suited; see [Maarten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72685373/1898563).

Answer (score 7):

It can be done via String or rather a CharBuffer as Holger commented.

```
char[] flatten(List<char[]> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .map(CharBuffer::wrap) // Better than String::new
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
        .toCharArray();
}
```

This requires "completed" array without any incomplete surrogate pair of chars at begin or end.

So compare this with:

```
char[] flatten(List<char[]> list) {
    int totalLength = list.stream().mapToInt(a -> a.length).sum();
    char[] totalArray = new char[totalLength];
    int i = 0;
    for (char[] array : list) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, totalArray, i, array.length);
        i += array.length; 
    }
    return totalArray;
}
```

Not so big a difference, and more solid code.

Or bring the entire software on the immutable `String` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes changed it to `.mapToInt(a -> a.length())`  - looks indeed fishy. Your answer was interesting for two reasons: the *Buffer classes merit more usage. And `put` is so nicely abstract.  It might use `SCOPED_MEMORY_ACCESS.copyMemory`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks again. CharBuffer goes in the direction of Maarten's answer which already has more votes. Maybe it can improve his answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution with Stream API which doesn't entail an **additional memory allocation**, which inevitably happens it you're using `String` and `StringBuilder` (because even with Java 8 it's not possible to instantiate a `String` without making an intermediate copy of the data, and `StringBuilder` will give you access to it's underlying array instead it gives you copy, and more over since Java 9 both `String` and `StringBuilder` are backed by `byte[]` arrays and not arrays of character).

Firstly, it makes sense to calculate the size of the resulting array (*as has been already mentioned by @Maarten Bodewes and @Michael in their answers*), which is a pretty fast operation because we are not processing the data of these arrays but only requesting the length of each of them.

And then in order to construct the *resulting array* we can make use of the *collector* which accumulates stream elements into the underlying `char[]` array and then hands it out when all the stream elements has been processes without any intermediate transformations and allocating additional memory.

All functions of the *collector* need to be stateless and changes should happen only inside its *mutable container*. Hence, we need a *mutable container* wraps a `char[]` array, but it should not have a *strong encapsulation* like `StringBuilder`, i.e. allowing access to its underlying array. And we can achieve that with `CharBuffer`.

So basically below the same idea that was introduced in the [*answer by @Maarten Bodewes*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72685373/17949945) fully implemented with streams.

`CharBuffer.allocate(length)` under the hood will instantiate `char[]` of the given length, and `CharBuffer.array()` will return the **same array** without generating an additional copy.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<char[]> listOfCharArrays =
        List.of(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'},
                new char[]{'d', 'e', 'f'},
                new char[]{'g', 'h', 'i'});

    char[] charArray = listOfCharArrays.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.summingInt(arr -> arr.length),  // calculating the total length of the arrays in the list
            length -> listOfCharArrays.stream().collect(
                Collector.of(
                    () -> CharBuffer.allocate(length), // mutable container of the collector
                    CharBuffer::put,                   // accumulating stream elements inside the container
                    CharBuffer::put,                   // merging the two containers with partial results (runs only when stream is being executed in parallel)
                    CharBuffer::array                  // finisher function performs the final transformation
                ))
        ));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArray));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
```

Comment: @Holger It wasn't supposed to be simpler. Motivation behind this post is introducing a fully stream based solution that doesn't causes overheads by making additional copies like all other solutions do, except of *Maarten Bodewes’s* solution.

Comment: @Holger Fixed the combiner. My initial thought that brought me to decision to disallow the usage of collector in parallel, was that a cost of allocating multiple buffers having the length of the target array (when it's really massive) can significantly increase the memory consumption.

Comment: Yes, using this with a parallel stream would raise the memory consumption and add avoidable copying overhead, but this is not a unique scenario. There are a lot of cases where turning a Stream to parallel would harm the performance. But at least, the result should stay correct. • Indeed, `StringBuilder` based approaches have additional copying overhead, sometimes even more than expected. Since Java 9, the internal array uses one byte per character, until encountering the first non-latin character. Then, the entire contents has to be inflated.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, I understand that. So let me conclude your message to make sure that I got it correctly: collector should not be brought into existence if it doesn't facilitate parallel execution at all, right?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko in general, you shouldn’t use the Stream API at all, if you have to add comments like “doesn’t work in parallel” or “assumes implementation detail xyz”. In fact, not being able to provide a correct merge function implies both, assuming an implementation detail (“only parallel streams use the merge function”) and requiring sequential execution.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the best solution, but you can use:

```
char[] chars = tableRowContainingOnlyRequestedColumns.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
        .toCharArray();
```